# Is it possible to add a logic Constraint to a Foreign Key?

Tags: sql, t-sql, foreign-keys, constraints

I've got two tables and I've added a foreign key constraint. Kewl - works great. Now, is it possible to further constrain that relationship against some data in the parent table?

Basically, I have animals in the parent table, and for the child table wishto only contain data where the parent data are .... um .. mammals.

eg.

```
Animals
^^^^^^^
AnimalId INT PK NOT NULL IDENTITY
AnimalType TINYINT NOT NULL -- 1: Mammal, 2:Reptile, etc..
Name

Mammals
^^^^^^^
AnimalId INT PK FK NOT NULL
NumberOfMammaryGlads TINYINT NOT NULL
```

So, i wishto make sure that the AnimalId can only be of type Animals.AnimalType = 1

Is this possible??

I don't want to allow someone to try and insert some info against a reptile, in the child table...

Cheers :)

#### Edit:

I thought I had to use a [Check Constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188258.aspx) (confirmed below from my first two answers - cheers!), but I wasn't sure how to (eg. the sql syntax to refer to the Animals table).

#### Update:

Alex has a very good post (below) that benchmarks some of the suggestions.... a very good read!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ran a small benchmark - in this case the approach with a UDF runs almost 100 times slower.

#### The overhead of an FK in CPU time = 375 ms - 297 ms = 78 ms

#### The overhead of an UDF in CPU time = 7750 ms - 297 ms = 7453 ms

Here's the Sql code...

-- set up an auxiliary table Numbers with 128K rows:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Numbers(n INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY)
GO
DECLARE @i INT;
SET @i = 1;
INSERT INTO dbo.Numbers(n) SELECT 1;
WHILE @i<128000 BEGIN
  INSERT INTO dbo.Numbers(n)
    SELECT n + @i FROM dbo.Numbers;
  SET @i = @i * 2;
END;
GO
```

-- the tables

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Animals
(AnimalId INT NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
AnimalType TINYINT NOT NULL, -- 1: Mammal, 2:Reptile, etc..
Name VARCHAR(30))
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.Animals
ADD CONSTRAINT UNQ_Animals UNIQUE(AnimalId, AnimalType)
GO
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetAnimalType(@AnimalId INT)
RETURNS TINYINT
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @ret TINYINT;
SELECT @ret = AnimalType FROM dbo.Animals
  WHERE AnimalId = @AnimalId;
RETURN @ret;
END
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.Mammals
(AnimalId INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
SomeOtherStuff VARCHAR(10),
CONSTRAINT Chk_AnimalType_Mammal CHECK(dbo.GetAnimalType(AnimalId)=1)
);
GO
```

--- populating with UDF:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Animals
  (AnimalType, Name)
SELECT 1, 'some name' FROM dbo.Numbers;
GO
SET STATISTICS IO ON
SET STATISTICS TIME ON
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.Mammals
(AnimalId,SomeOtherStuff)
SELECT n, 'some info' FROM dbo.Numbers;
```

results are:

```
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 2 ms.
Table 'Mammals'. Scan count 0, logical reads 272135, 
    physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, 
    lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Numbers'. Scan count 1, logical reads 441, physical reads 0, 
    read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, 
    lob read-ahead reads 0.

SQL Server Execution Times:
    CPU time = 7750 ms,  elapsed time = 7830 ms.

(131072 row(s) affected)
```

--- populating with FK:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Mammals2
(AnimalId INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
AnimalType TINYINT NOT NULL,
SomeOtherStuff VARCHAR(10),
CONSTRAINT Chk_Mammals2_AnimalType_Mammal CHECK(AnimalType=1),
CONSTRAINT FK_Mammals_Animals FOREIGN KEY(AnimalId, AnimalType)
  REFERENCES dbo.Animals(AnimalId, AnimalType)
);

INSERT INTO dbo.Mammals2
(AnimalId,AnimalType,SomeOtherStuff)
SELECT n, 1, 'some info' FROM dbo.Numbers;
```

results are:

```
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 93 ms, elapsed time = 100 ms.
Table 'Animals'. Scan count 1, logical reads 132, physical reads 0,
    read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, 
    lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Mammals2'. Scan count 0, logical reads 275381, physical reads 0,
   read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, 
   lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Numbers'. Scan count 1, logical reads 441, physical reads 0,
   read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, 
   lob read-ahead reads 0.

SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 375 ms,  elapsed time = 383 ms.
```

-- populating without any integrity:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Mammals3
(AnimalId INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
SomeOtherStuff VARCHAR(10)
);
INSERT INTO dbo.Mammals3
(AnimalId,SomeOtherStuff)
SELECT n,  'some info' FROM dbo.Numbers;
```

results are:
    SQL Server parse and compile time: 
       CPU time = 1 ms, elapsed time = 1 ms.

```
SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 66 ms.
Table 'Mammals3'. Scan count 0, logical reads 272135, physical reads 0,
    read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0,
    lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Numbers'. Scan count 1, logical reads 441, physical reads 0, 
    read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, 
    lob read-ahead reads 0.

SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 297 ms,  elapsed time = 303 ms.

(131072 row(s) affected)
```

The overhead of an FK in CPU time = 375 ms - 297 ms = 78 ms
The overhead of an UDF in CPU time = 7750 ms - 297 ms = 7453 ms

Comment: So it looks like the fastest solution is to have no relationship/constraint. This is not good for a data integrity perspective. Next is to have th FK solution. Even though this seems like we're doubling up the data on the FK field, the cost of this seems to be worth it over the performance benefits, vs having a check contraint that calls a UDF. Do other people agree with me (and AlexK) on this summary?

Answer (score 6):

Have a unique constraint on Animals(AnimalId, AnimalType)
Add AnimalType to Mammals, and use a check constraint to make sure it is always 1.
Have a FK refer to (AnimalId, AnimalType).

Comment: Duplicating the animalType column on the Mammals table is not advisable, as this increases the table size and goes against data normalization best practices.

Comment: The increase in size is minor, and all your logic gets much much simpler. You'll save a lot in CPU cycles and development time.

Comment: Denormalizing to enforce business rules also described here:
http://www.devx.com/dbzone/Article/34479/1954
and here:
http://sqlblog.com/blogs/alexander_kuznetsov/archive/2009/01/23/denormalizing-to-enforce-business-rules-running-totals.aspx

Comment: @Alex: it's still a bad idea, whena trigger or UDF could do it.

Comment: Just want to point out that the links point to articles you have written yourself - and at the end of the article (yes, I read it) you say yourself that the cost of using referential integrity is steep. I would suggest that a data access layer outside of SQL should be used to enforce business rules.  A database is designed for serving data - not implementing business logic.

Comment: @Jeff - i agree with that .. but if it's 'cheap' to have some simple data integrity in the DB, I would like to enforce that, there. If it becomes costly (eg. my Function in the Check Constraint is 'expensive') then I'm happy to drop it. For me, this is very basic and simple data integrety. Business rules should always be outside of the DB. i see this as simple data rules.

Comment: Jeff, databases are all about managing data, including its integrity.  Enforcing data integrity rules outside of the database makes no sense whatsoever!  Creating a UNIQUE constraint like this to propagate the subtype down into the child table is a common practice and is relatively harmless in terms of normalisation and performance.

Comment: Yes, this is common, almost like a SQL 'design pattern', It's usually referred to as 'subclassing'.

Comment: @Jeff, I'd hate to see the data integrity in any database you work with. Data integrity rules should always be enforced at the database level. The application is NOT the only thing that can affect data. This is a rule that must always apply no matter where the data came from and it belongs in the database.

Comment: @gbn, check constraints are often better for performance than trigger and far better than a UDF. Check constraints are the first place to enforce a business rule, a trigger should be used only if the logic is so complex  that the constraint cannot do the job.

Comment: @gbn,

The following link describes that the UDF approach has loopholes:
http://www.devx.com/dbzone/Article/31985/0/page/3

Comment: @Alex: ...and denormalising data has no issues? YOu may never hit the udf issue but at some point your denormalised data will be out of synch. @HLGEM: A trigger is one solution that avoids denormalising *and* the UDF hole (note UDF is in a check constraint anyway)

Comment: @gbn: because animalType in the child table is included in the FK constraint, the constraint guarantees that animalType value always matches the value in the parent table. As long as the constraint is trusted of course. MVP Hugo Kornelis wrote about trusted constraints:
http://sqlblog.com/blogs/hugo_kornelis/archive/2007/03/29/can-you-trust-your-constraints.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can create a CHECK CONSTRAINT on the column.

```
ALTER TABLE Mammals
ADD CONSTRAINT CHK_AnimalType CHECK (dbo.fnGetAnimalType(animalId) = 1 );
```

Now you need a function fnGetAnimalType that will return the animalType of the given animalId.

Here is more [info from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188258.aspx).

Comment: Ah... i need to do this via a FUNCTION! ahhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh... brb :)

Comment: It will surely run very slowly

Comment: @Alex, a check constraint will affect performance, but your claim that it will run very slowly is very premature.

Comment: @Alex: it checks only on insert or update: your denormalised solution would still need a lookup onto Animals. The udf approach is cleaner

Answer (score 1):

To give a strong guarantee, you'll need two check constraints going both ways. If you only constrain `Mammals` someone could update `Animals.AnimalType` and get the data in an inconsistent state.

Comment: Good point.  After a record is created in Mammals, someone could change the AnimalType in Animals and now you have an invalid condition.  Hopefully this would not be likely but could happen if an animal is actually reclassified from mammal to something else or someone made a data entry error to begin with in the Animal table.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use a Check constraint within the Mammals table.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188258.aspx

Comment: @Tet: I don't wish to check against the AnimalId value, but against the Animals.AnimalTypeId value.

Comment: Ah - true - I reverted it to my original answer - to check against the AnimalType - you will need to call a function - which as Alex says in another comment may have an affect on performance.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like table inheritance - I recently asked a question (can't link because I'm too new here!) whose answer lead to finding [this solution](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/implementing-table-inheritance-in-sql-server).

I'm working with monetary Transactions where a Transaction is the parent table and transaction types such as Cheque, Bank Transfer, and CC are the child tables.  Using a lookup table for transaction types, foreign key constraints, and computed columns I was able to enforce the type constraint on each of the child tables.

Check out the article for implementation details.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative approach that builds on the technique discussed in "[Enforcing Complex Constraints with Indexed Views](http://spaghettidba.com/2011/08/03/enforcing-complex-constraints-with-indexed-views/)" to enforce the `AnimalType` constraint. The advantage of this approach is that it avoids the extra column in the subtype table; however, it is slower than the composite foreign key presented in [AlexKuznetsov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1038685/1149773) (although nowhere near as abysmally slow as the UDF approach).

I ran the same series of tests as AlexKuznetsov, but increased the number of rows from 131,072 to 1,048,576. Here is a summary of the results:

```
-- No integrity check:                         2488 ms.
-- With composite foreign key:                 4404 ms.
-- With indexed view and unique index:         7063 ms. <- new
-- With check constraint calling scalar UDF:  78304 ms.
```

Schema definitions:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Mammals4
(
    AnimalId INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
        REFERENCES dbo.Animals (AnimalId),
    SomeOtherStuff VARCHAR(10)
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.TwoRows   -- can be reused for other similar indexed views
(
    n TINYINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
)

INSERT INTO dbo.TwoRows
VALUES (1), (2)

GO

CREATE VIEW dbo.CK_Mammals4 WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
    SELECT M.AnimalId
    FROM dbo.Mammals4 M
        JOIN dbo.Animals A
            ON A.AnimalId = M.AnimalId
        CROSS JOIN dbo.TwoRows
    WHERE A.AnimalType != 1

GO

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX CKIX_Mammals4
ON dbo.CK_Mammals4 (AnimalId)
```

Tests and results:

```
-- No integrity check:

INSERT INTO dbo.Mammals3 (AnimalId, SomeOtherStuff)
SELECT n, 'some info' FROM dbo.Numbers;

Table 'Mammals3'. Scan count 0, logical reads 2969171, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Numbers'. Scan count 1, logical reads 1724, physical reads 3, read-ahead reads 1720, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 2247 ms,  elapsed time = 2488 ms.

-- With composite foreign key:

INSERT INTO dbo.Mammals2 (AnimalId, AnimalType, SomeOtherStuff)
SELECT n, 1, 'some info' FROM dbo.Numbers;

Table 'Animals'. Scan count 1, logical reads 1432, physical reads 3, read-ahead reads 1428, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Mammals2'. Scan count 0, logical reads 3163291, physical reads 3, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Numbers'. Scan count 1, logical reads 1724, physical reads 3, read-ahead reads 1720, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 3822 ms,  elapsed time = 4404 ms.

-- With indexed view and unique index:

INSERT INTO dbo.Mammals4 (AnimalId, SomeOtherStuff)
SELECT n, 'some info' FROM dbo.Numbers

Table 'CK_Mammals4'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Animals'. Scan count 2, logical reads 4953, physical reads 6, read-ahead reads 4945, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 2, logical reads 2978842, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Mammals4'. Scan count 0, logical reads 3162616, physical reads 3, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Numbers'. Scan count 1, logical reads 1724, physical reads 3, read-ahead reads 1720, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 6209 ms,  elapsed time = 7063 ms.

-- With check constraint calling scalar UDF:

INSERT INTO dbo.Mammals (AnimalId, SomeOtherStuff)
SELECT n, 'some info' FROM dbo.Numbers;

Table 'Mammals'. Scan count 0, logical reads 2969171, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Numbers'. Scan count 1, logical reads 1724, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 77424 ms,  elapsed time = 78304 ms.
```