# How to ensure that a attribute has a specific value?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, constraints

Let's say I have a class `Car` that has a `Manufacturer` and a `Color`. A `Manifacturer` defines in which colors a car can be possibly painted. Car, Color and Manufacturer are all tables I have modelled using declarative_base in SQLAlchemy. Color is a complex class that has some attributes.

I want to restrict the color of a car to the colors specified via the manufacturer. Can I restrict the Color a Car gets in SQLAlchemy using a contraint or something similar or do I have to check that in pure Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe [sqlalchemy.types.Enum](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/core/types.html#sqlalchemy.types.Enum) should handle what you need to handle a defined list of strings.

> The Enum type provides a set of possible string values which the column is constrained towards.
>   By default, uses the backend’s native ENUM type if available, else uses VARCHAR + a CHECK constraint.

But looking at it from an object constraint level I imagine you can handle it with a ForeignKey with a Check constraint, but it seems the check contraints just pass it directly through to the database, so it will differ depending on what dbms you're running.  [This question goes deeper into the SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036217/is-it-possible-to-add-a-logic-constraint-to-a-foreign-key) which should be able to be paired up with [SQLAlchemy's Constraints](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/schema.html#check-constraint).

A cleaner, more portable way might be to build it into your constructor, or just have a function that can validate the data before the query is fired

```
## Using the Car constructor for validation

def __init__(self,color,manufacturer,price=1000):
    if color in manufacturer.allowed_colors:
        self.color = color
        self.manufacturer
    else:
        raise LookupError() # or something more relevant.
    self.price = price

## Or just a generic function that can be called:

def validate_car(color,manufacturer):
    if color in manufacturer.allowed_colors:
        return true
    return false

if validate_car(color,manufacturer):
    car = Car(color,manufacturer)
    session.add(car)
```

If it were me, this validation would live on the outskirts of my application.  Assuming a Web app, that would mean it would be validated on the form level-- only relevant car colours would be shown to the user, and then the server would validate the chosen colour to make sure no users are squeezing in bad data.  So I would have a function to `validate_car(color,manufacturer)` but it would be called when the form was being processedm if the form checked out, then I'd create and add the Car object.

Having the constraint within the dbms itself would be fun for cascading deletions, e.g. if Ford decided to stop selling Blue cars, then you could just delete Blue and all Blue Ford cars would magically disappear, again though, I think if you were to go the constraint route, it would almost be manual SQL to hook it all up (though I would enjoy to learn if it isn't!).

Comment: I added a clarification. The Colors are not just simple Strings :( But thanks!

Comment: I too quickly skimmed over the need for each manufacturer to have a different set of colours, hopefully the edited answer might be useful.