# Unique entries in different tables

Tags: sql

I have a `person` table with a primary key called `id`. I want 2 other tables called `teacher_table` and `student_table` which both have foreign keys referenced to a `person.id`.

How can I make sure a student can't be a teacher?

Edit: Is it convention to do these sorts of contrains in a stored procedure or something? because what if you get very complicated relationships, just the table constraints can't do that right?

Comment: even number for student, odd number for teacher ?!?! :/

Comment: Yes, but thern everytime I'd want a specific teacher, I'd need to go trough the full person table so that wouldn't be an option...

Comment: This sounds like a normalization issue. Your problem can be avoided by simply having 1 general table for all "users" (or whatever scenario you're constructing) and the other 2 tables, `tbl_teachers` & `tbl_students`, will be deciding what type of user they are. If the user ID from the users table exists in the teachers table, they're a teacher. If the user ID exists in the students table, then they're a student. This logic will also be very future proof and expandable, should you want more logic in the future. It keeps things "abstract".

Comment: Can be done in Oracle or PostgreSQL. What database are you using? Also, can a `person` be abstract? that is, having no related row in `teacher` o `student`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Enforcing exclusivity in table inheritance: composite foreign key vs check constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24025167/enforcing-exclusivity-in-table-inheritance-composite-foreign-key-vs-check-const)

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution allows abstract `person` rows that may not have corresponding *concrete* rows in `student` or `teacher`.

You'll need a composite key on the main table, and should take the form:

```
create table person (
  id int primary key not null,
  type char(1) not null check (type in ('T', 'S')),
  unique (id, type)
  -- common properties here
);
 
create table teacher (
  id int not null,
  type char(1) check (type ='T'),
  foreign key (id, type) references person (id, type)
  -- teacher's properties here
);

create table student (
  id int not null,
  type char(1) check (type ='S'),
  foreign key (id, type) references person (id, type)
  -- student's properties here
);
```

If you need to enforce all entities are concrete, that can be done in Oracle or PostgreSQL by including a reverse foreign key constraint.

Comment: Yes, this seems good, but I'll definitly look into the reverse foreign key contraint!

Answer (score 0):

You could put some BEFORE INSERT triggers on the student & teacher tables.

Let the triggers check if a certain flag in the persons table corresponds with the expected flag for that table.

The example below works only in a Postgresql RDBMS.

> ```
> create table person (
>  id serial primary key, 
>  first_name varchar(30), 
>  last_name varchar(100), 
>  person_type char(1) not null check (person_type in ('T','S')), 
>  unique (first_name, last_name)
> );
>
> create table student_table (
>  student_id serial primary key, 
>  person_id int, 
>  grade int, 
>  foreign key (person_id) references person(id), 
>  unique (person_id)
> );
>
> create table teacher_table (
>  teacher_id serial primary key, 
>  person_id int, 
>  nickname varchar(30), 
>  foreign key (person_id) references person(id), 
>  unique (person_id)
> );
> ```

> ```
> insert into person (person_type, first_name, last_name) values 
>   ('S', 'Anna', 'Brandi')
> , ('T', 'Bob', 'Modest')
> ```

Creating a UDF for the triggers to use

> ```
> CREATE FUNCTION check_person_type()  
> RETURNS trigger 
> AS $check_person_type$
> DECLARE current_person_type char(1);
> DECLARE new_person_type varchar(1);
>     BEGIN
>         
>         new_person_type := TG_ARGV[0];
>         
>         SELECT INTO current_person_type person_type
>         FROM person 
>         WHERE id = NEW.person_id;
>         
>         -- teacher check
>         IF current_person_type = 'T' AND new_person_type != 'T' THEN
>             RAISE EXCEPTION 'Person with id % is a teacher', NEW.person_id;
>         END IF;
>
>         -- student check
>         IF current_person_type = 'S' AND new_person_type != 'S' THEN
>             RAISE EXCEPTION 'Person with id % is a student', NEW.person_id;
>         END IF;
>         
>         RETURN NEW;
>     END;
> $check_person_type$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
> ```

The triggers

> ```
> CREATE TRIGGER check_student_person_type BEFORE INSERT ON student_table
>     FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE check_person_type('S');
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TRIGGER check_teacher_person_type BEFORE INSERT ON teacher_table
>     FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE check_person_type('T');
> ```

Doing something bad

> ```
> -- Trying to enroll teacher Bob as a student
> insert into student_table (person_id, grade)
> select id, 99 as grade
> from person 
> where (first_name, last_name) = ('Bob', 'Modest');
> ```
>
> ```
> ERROR:  Person with id 2 is a teacher
> ```

CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function check_person_type() line 14 at RAISE

> 

> ```
> -- Trying to enroll Anna as a teacher
> insert into teacher_table (person_id, nickname)
> select id, 'sweety pie' as nickname
> from person 
> where (first_name, last_name) = ('Anna', 'Brandi');
> ```
>
> ```
> ERROR:  Person with id 1 is a student
> ```

CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function check_person_type() line 19 at RAISE

> 

Trying better this time

> ```
> insert into student_table (person_id, grade)
> select id, 1 as grade
> from person 
> where (first_name, last_name) = ('Anna', 'Brandi');
> select * from student_table limit 1;
> ```
>
> ```
> student_id | person_id | grade
> ---------: | --------: | ----:
>          2 |         1 |     1
> ```

> ```
> insert into teacher_table (person_id, nickname)
> select id, 'the goat' as nickname
> from person 
> where (first_name, last_name) = ('Bob', 'Modest');
> select * from teacher_table limit 1;
> ```
>
> ```
> teacher_id | person_id | nickname
> ---------: | --------: | :-------
>          2 |         2 | the goat
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=cdd9aaabe227af7cb0706b1b58fb602d)*

Comment: Seems like the OP is interested on ensuring data cannot violate the rules when storing it.